# How to add tags to ListView that is populated from a database?

Tags: android, listview

I have a table that contains a number of columns, including an autoincrementing ID and subject name. When my activity loads, the ListView gets populated with some of the subjects in the table. I am looking for a method to add the id as a tag on each of the ListView items so that I can tell which item is clicked on even if there are multiple entries with the same subject name. My current code:

Getting the subjects from the table:

```
public ArrayList getSubjects(int level){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor subjectCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + SUBJECTS_TABLE_NAME + " where " + SUBJECTS_COL_3 + "="+level,null);
    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(subjectCursor.moveToFirst(); !subjectCursor.isAfterLast(); subjectCursor.moveToNext()) {
        mArrayList.add(subjectCursor.getString(1));
    }
    return mArrayList;
}
```

Setting up the ListView:

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = myDb.getSubjects(1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.subject_list_item, mArrayList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // selected item
            String subject = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubjectActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("subject", subject);
            i.putExtra("level", 1);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

XML for the ListView items:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/subject_back"
android:textColor="#ffffffff"
android:textStyle="bold" >
```

Thanks for any suggestions or alternative options for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: you can get selected views position from  listview and from this position you can get item from arraylist

Comment: I'd probably change list item layout and include another textView which will hold the _id from database and when any item selected I can retrieve the id. @Tej position in listView can be different than the id in the database.

Comment: @Ranjan   its convenient to use List<Hashmap<String,String> rather than using external textview for storing id. She can store respective id in hashmap and get it  according to position.

Comment: did you see `OnItemClickListener`? the callback method gives you an `ID` of item that was clicked: `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

Comment: Hii @pskink, I'm unfamiliar with the callback method. Could you expand on that a little? I'll edit my question to include the OnItemClickListener in case that is helpful

Comment: just use `ListView#setOnItemClickListener` method

Comment: @pskink all of the ids on the ListView are set to 0

Comment: then use adapter that implements `getItemId` method properly: for example use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Hi @pskink, could you possibly submit a couple of lines of code as an answer? I'm new to using this and having code to follow makes it much easier to understand. I'm more than happy to accept it as a response even if it is just a simple fix that can be commented.

Comment: see https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: You need to use `position` not `id`

Comment: @Ranjan she need to use `id` not `position`

Comment: @pskink This `id` is different that what she wants it to be. She wants value from `_id` column of database.

Comment: @Ranjan then simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter` for example (or any subclass of `CursorAdapter`) - it is even more simple that `ArrayAdapter` (not speaking about  additional `HashMap`s and such things)